# Android create scaled and rotated Bitmap

Tags: android, exception, bitmap

The following code works to create a rotated and scaled Bitmap from another Bitmap bmpSrc:

```
                final int srcWidth = bmpSrc.getWidth();
                final int srcHeight = bmpSrc.getHeight();
                final float sx = (float)reqWidth  / (float)srcWidth;
                final float sy = (float)reqHeight / (float)srcHeight;

                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                m.setScale(sx, sy);
                final float px = (float) srcWidth / 2;
                final float py = (float) srcHeight / 2;
                m.setRotate(270, px, py);

                bmpFillScreen = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpSrc, 0, 0, reqHeight, reqWidth, m, true);
```

But on some devices (especially 10 inch tablets) it throws this Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:554)
```

What can I do to solve that?

Comment: Is your bitmap big enough? ie. it probably doesn't work on 12 inch tablets either or other high density pixel screen tablets?

Comment: Also have you looked into using: createScaledBitmap instead?

Comment: Thanks, using a larger bmp solves the problem.